# Windows Live Mesh: "It is already being synced, contains folders that are already being synced, or is in a folder that is already being synced."

Tags: windows-live, windows-live-mesh

On my Windows 7 x64 laptop, I'm trying to sync My Documents using Mesh (version 15.4.3502.922) but I keep getting this error:

> This folder can't be synced.  It is
>   already being synced, contains folders
>   that are already being synced, or is
>   in a folder that is already being
>   synced. Please select a different
>   folder or move this folder to another
>   location.

But this folder ISN'T being synced.  If I go to devices.live.com and browse the node for my laptop, it says:

> You aren't syncing any folders. To
>   start syncing a folder, make sure
>   Windows Live Mesh is installed on this
>   computer. Then start Windows Live Mesh
>   and click Sync a folder.

I get the same error when trying to sync "My Videos" and "My Photos".  These 3 folders were synced using a different hotmail account on my old laptop.  These folders were copied from that old laptop to my new laptop.  On this new laptop, I'm using a completely different Windows Live Id.  And this is the first time I'm using Mesh on this laptop.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I deleted pretty much everything under "C:\users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Live Mesh" and things worked as expected.